# Check status of the previous stage in Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, terraform, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I want to put the expression in when condition to check the previous stage status

I tried this
`return currentBuild.getPreviousBuild()?.getResult()?.toString() != 'ABORTED' && currentBuild.getPreviousBuild()?.getResult()?.toString() != 'FAILURE' "`  
But this expression is used to check the status of prevous **build** not **stage **

I aslo tried
`return currentBuild.getPreviousStageResult()?.getResult()?.toString() != 'ABORTED' && currentBuild.getPreviousBuild()?.getResult()?.toString() != 'FAILURE' "`

but didnt worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example to check the status of the previous stage in a Jenkins pipeline, May be this can help you.

```
    def previousBuild = currentBuild.getPreviousBuild()
    if (previousBuild) {
       def previousBuildResult = previousBuild.getResult()
       echo "Status of the previous build: ${previousBuildResult}"
    } else {
       echo "No previous build found."
    }
```

Comment: This Example is for Checking previous build not Previous Stage, Thanks for your response